# Find a presentation for the fundamental group of $P^2\#T$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I have to find a presentation for the fundamental group of $ P^2\# T $. Which I believe to be identified by the following labeling scheme: $(a_1b_1a_1b_1)(a_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1})$. $P^2$ is the projective plane and T is the torus. I honestly have no idea how to tackle this. Kind regards :)

Comment: what is # $\hspace{1cm}$

Comment: Have you tried getting a presentation using van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: Hint: $P^2$ has the surface word $aa$, $T$ has the surface word $bcb^{-1}c^{-1}$. Then the connected sum $P^2 \# T$ has the surface word $aabcb^{-1}c^{-1}$. That is, $P^2 \# T$ is a wedge of 3 circles w/ a 2-cell attached along the above word. Now apply the Van-Kampen version for attaching 2-cells.

Comment: Why does $P^2$ have $aa$ and not $abab$ as surface word? And how do you quickly see that $P^2\#T$ is a wedge of 3 circles w/ a 2-cell attached.

Comment: Both of those surface words yield $P^2$. Write down the fundamental polygon w/ the surface word $aabcb^{-1}c^{-1}$ but delete the interior. Try to convince yourself that making the prescribed identifications yields a wedge of three circles. Then the space $P^2 \# T$ is obtained from that by "filling out the interior", i.e. attaching a 2-cell along the path word $aabcb^{-1}c^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about van Kampen's theorem. The natural decomposition corresponds to open sets that look like punctured copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $T^2$ intersecting in an open annulus. The fundamental group is then the free product of $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2\setminus \{pt\})$ and $\pi_1(T^2 \setminus \{pt\})$ with an additional relation that comes from analyzing the loop in the intersection. I'm happy to give a more complete answer if need be, but this hint should probably suffice.

Comment: Hey this helps, I will need some time to think about it. If I can't figure it out(mostly the analyzing the loop in the intersection part). I'll get back to you :)